# How to make IMPORTRANGE a dynamic function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

Is there any way to make the below formula as a dynamic array formula:

`=query(
{IMPORTRANGE(B2,"Filter!B:C");
 importrange(B3,"Filter!B:C");
 importrange(B4,"Filter!B:C")},"Where Col2 <>''")`

If my input will be three spreadsheet keys then IMPORTRANGE should execute three times, if my input is five spreadsheet keys then IMPORTRANGE should execute five times.

Comment: Your formula looks ok to me. To add another keys, you need to add them into the formula.

Comment: Hi Max, Is there a way where the importrange will act as a dynamic function.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this Q is no, you can't.

`importrange` is already an `arrayformula` in some way because it returns array, so it can't take an array of keys\ranges as input.

## Workaround

You may combine the the formula as string, get string like this:

`"=query({importrange(...);importrange(...)...},"select...")"`

and then use script to convert the string into formula.

---

for example, make `ini` sheet, in col `A` make list of importranges:

```
="importrange("&B1&",""Filter!B:C"")"
="importrange("&B2&",""Filter!B:C"")"
="importrange("&B3&",""Filter!B:C"")"
and so on
```

Put keys in col `B`.

then make filter formula to join them with semicolon:

`= join(";", filter (A:A, A:A <> "")`

so you get the part of future formula:

`"importrange(B2,"Filter!B:C");importrange(B3,"Filter!B:C");..."`

and then concatenate another parts of the formula.

Final step is to use script to convert this text formula and paste it as actual formula to the target sheet. Script may work dinamically if you use `onEdit` trigger to check any changes in `ini` sheet.